# How to make data gridview as a Calendar weekly view in C# Windows Application

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am developing a Windows application in C#. I have one requirement to display calendar with Weekly , monthly and daily view. I have downloaded many calendars from codeproject, but none of them meet my requirement. I need the format as following,

```
           Day & Date1   Day&Date2   Day&Date3 .................. end of week
           -----------   ---------
           -----------   ---------
```

Emp Name1      -----------   ---------

Emp Name2

Emp Name3
.........

.........

For each employee, each day in the week should be divided into 3 shifts and on right clicking on each shift we can associate employee to customer. How can I do this ? How can I generate this week view calendar ?? Its urgent..Please help dear friends.. Can I render datagridview as week view calendar with two buttons on top, one to move forward (next week) and other to move backward (previous week).. Any help is highly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: At the risk of sounding like a big horrible jerk, I'd say you make this way the way you make anything else: one step at a time, satisfying your requirements. You're not really asking a question here but fishing for someone to write an entire control for you. If you hope to get anything you should probably specify whether you're working in Forms or WPF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [A Professional Calendar](http://bettercalendar.codeplex.com/)

It's open source and may meet your needs.